# Can I use two or more content processor for an xna project?

Tags: animation, model, xna, collision

I have a game project but I need to use two ContentProccesor one for proccesing the colissions using the triangle of the mesh and other for animating the model reading the data of the animation and the skeleton. But when I try to use the two ContentProcessor for different models, the environment model the collision processor and for animate the model the animation proccesor, in the ContentProcessor only appears one of them.

Can I use the two ContentProcessors or XNA is restricted to just one?

Thanks